# Importing data from a text file using deserialization but text is not showing in the text fields

Tags: java, io

I started by exporting the data from the text fields to a text file. To do so I used serialization. This is the code

```
public void save()
{
try {
    File selectedFile = new File(ConsultantID + ".txt");
    FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(selectedFile);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
    oos.writeObject(this);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
}

private String toString(int ConsultantID) {
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

To load the data back from the file I am using deserialization. The below is the code I am using for this

```
public static Consultant load()


{

Consultant load = null;

JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int chooserOption = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
chooserOption = JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION;
try {


File file = new File (chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());


ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new     FileInputStream(file));



load = (Consultant) input.readObject();


input.close();



return load;




 } catch (IOException ex) {
System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
 }
 return null;
```

I do not have errors and the file loader is showing. But when I select the file the program does not put the data in to the text fields. I created a load button using the following code:

```
Consultant consl = new Consultant();
this.jTextField1.setText(consl.getConsfirstname());
this.jTextField2.setText(consl.getConslastname());
this.jTextField3.setText(consl.getConsultantID());
consl.load()
```

Do you think I have missed something in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple to things.

- you appear to set the text of the labels before you load the data.
- you load the data and then discard the object returned.

I suggest you load the data first, and then use the object the load() function returns to set the values.